# Change Visual Studio 2019 Theme time-controlled (Day/Night Mode for Theme)

Tags: visual-studio, themes

During the day I find the bright standard theme of Visual Studio pleasant, while in the evening I often switch to the dark theme when the ambient light decreases.
In Visual Studio Code there are plugins to switch between themes time-controlled.

Is there anything equivalent in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: Go to `Settings` -> `Environment` -> `General`, on the right pane there is `Color Theme` setting. (I've non-English locale in VS, not sure if I translated UI correctly)

Comment: First video I've found in YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RECDMCe8i5U). Basically, go to `Settings` and type `Auto Detect Color Scheme`

Answer (score 15):

There is an extension for Visual Studio 2019 called **Auto Theme Switcher for Win10 Dark Mode** (can be found in the extensions menu or @microsoft [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NickJohn.AutoThemeSwitcherForWin10DarkMode)).

Then you can configure your light and dark theme in the options.

*Note: I'm not the author of this extension, just a user that was in the same situation and found that extension.*

Answer (score -4):

Set the color theme for the Visual Studio IDE
The default color theme for Visual Studio's user interface is called Blue. Let's change it to Dark.

1. On the menu bar, which is the row of menus such as File and Edit,
   choose Tools > Options.
2. On the Environment > General options page, change the Color theme
   selection to Dark, and then choose OK.

   The color theme for the entire Visual Studio development environment (IDE) changes to Dark.